# Export command in Mathematica trial version

Tags: export

*Mathematica* trial version does not support `Export[]` command.

Is there a command equivalent to `Export[]` in order to export, say, a matrix?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472425/cant-use-export-with-mathematica-trial-version

Comment: Which format are you trying to export?